# Remove large files after Visual Studio diagnostics session

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, diagnostics

After a `Visual Studio 2015` diagnostics session there are large files like `Report45188264-1551.vspx`, having a size of 320 MB or more.

Must I delete those files manually or is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Do you in general like to have performance analyzed or do you want to turn it off completely?

Comment: @Thomas: I don't want to turn it off, the best would be if the files are deleted when Visual Studio shuts down.